# Extract embedded TIFFs in TIKA 1.12 vs TIKA 1.14

Tags: pdfbox, tiff, apache-tika

My goal is to convert pdf to xhtml such that embedded images can be linked correctly in the html.

The code below works in TIKA 1.12 but not 1.14. It appears the problem is that in 1.12, PDFBox 1.8 was used, and in 1.14, PDFBox 2.0 is used.

In 1.14, I get font errors and tiff errors, e.g.

```
WARN org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont - No Unicode mapping for g74 (103) in font HFKECA+TimesNewRoman

ERROR org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil - No ImageWriter found for 'tif' format
```

From various forums and looking at the TIKA source it seemed I needed to include `jai_imageio.jar` to my path for the tiffs. That did not stop the errors. I also tried adding the following with it and swapping it out with `jai-imageio-core-1.3.1.jar` (the github version):

```
jempbox-1.8.13.jar
fontbox-2.0.4.jar
levigo-jbig2-imageio-1.6.5.jar
```

Again, none of those jars seemed to do anything. However, using the TIKA 1.12 jar by itself gives perfect results.

What do I need to do to make TIKA 1.14 run without these warnings (as TIKA 1.12 does)?

```
/**
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

package org.apache.tika.example;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig;
import org.apache.tika.detect.Detector;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.extractor.EmbeddedDocumentExtractor;
import org.apache.tika.extractor.ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor;
import org.apache.tika.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MediaType;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParserConfig;

public class ExtractEmbeddedFiles {

  private Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
  private Detector detector = ((AutoDetectParser)parser).getDetector();
  private TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();

  public void extract(String inputPath) throws SAXException, TikaException, IOException {

    File inputFile = new File(inputPath);
    String parentDirectory = inputFile.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getPath();

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    File outputDirectory = new File(parentDirectory, inputFile.getName() + "-extracted" );


    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ToXMLContentHandler handler = new org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler();

    PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
    pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);

    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();

    parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
    parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser); 

    EmbeddedDocumentExtractor ex = new MyEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(outputDirectory.toPath(), parseContext);
    parseContext.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class, ex);

    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    parser.parse(inputStream, handler, metadata, parseContext);

    String text = handler.toString().trim();

    File outputFile = new File(outputDirectory, inputFile.getName() + ".xhtml" );


     PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(
       new FileOutputStream( outputFile.getPath()  ),
       Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder() 
 )));
    printer.print( text );
    printer.close();

  }

  private class MyEmbeddedDocumentExtractor extends ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor {
    private final Path outputDir;
    private int fileCount = 0;

    private MyEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(Path outputDir, ParseContext context) {
      super(context);
      this.outputDir = outputDir;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldParseEmbedded(Metadata metadata) {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void parseEmbedded(InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler, Metadata metadata, boolean outputHtml)
      throws SAXException, IOException {

      //try to get the name of the embedded file from the metadata
      String name = metadata.get(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY);

      if (name == null) {
        name = "file_" + fileCount++;
      } else {
        //make sure to select only the file name (not any directory paths
        //that might be included in the name) and make sure
        //to normalize the name
        name = FilenameUtils.normalize(FilenameUtils.getName(name));
      }

      //now try to figure out the right extension for the embedded file
      MediaType contentType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);

      if (name.indexOf('.')==-1 && contentType!=null) {
        try {
          name += config.getMimeRepository().forName(
          contentType.toString()).getExtension();
        } catch (MimeTypeException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      //should add check to make sure that you aren't overwriting a file
      Path outputFile = outputDir.resolve(name);

      //do a better job than this of checking
      Files.createDirectories(outputFile.getParent());
      Files.copy(stream, outputFile);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: run `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()));` at the start, what do you get?

Comment: with both TIKA 1.12 and 1.14 I get `[JPEG 2000, JPG, jpg, JPEG2000, tiff, bmp, BMP, gif, GIF, WBMP, png, PNG, raw, RAW, JPEG, pnm, PNM, tif, TIF, TIFF, jpeg2000, wbmp, jpeg, jpeg 2000]`

Comment: Next thing to try: 1) `System.out.println(ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tif").next());` 2) create a BufferedImage and then call `ImageIOUtil.write(bim,"tif",new FileOutputStream(....),72,1);` does this produce a file? If that doesn't give a clue, I would try your code... does this happen with any PDF or only with some?

Comment: btw the font warning is harmless... it just means that some glyph doesn't have any unicode associated with it in the font, i.e. it won't appear in text extraction.

Comment: On version 1.14, executing `System.out.println(javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tif").next());` yields `com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter@533fe14f`. Executing `java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.File ("/z/aolney/research_projects/braintrust/materials/NEETS/xhtml/Mod01 - Matter Energy and DC.pdf-extracted/image1.tif"));
org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image,"tif",new java.io.FileOutputStream("/z/aolney/research_projects/braintrust/materials/NEETS/image1.tif"),72,1);` yields a good tif file.

Comment: Using `java-8-oracle` specifically `java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`

Comment: That is what I'd expect... so I tested your code. It had a small bug (main was missing, and directory wasn't created). I was able to run it with a PDF file that has a .docx file embedded. I suspect that I'd need your specific file, or the information what's in this file so that I can look if I have a similar one.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I'm doing this in a notebook environment that does not require an explicit `main`. Thanks for your help BTW. I seem to have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but it seems to be working now with the following combination of libraries:

- tika-app-1.14.jar
- jai_imageio.jar

It may be that the problem was that I was originally using a different library for ImageIO.

There are a [variety of jai libraries available from Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaiimageio11jar.htm), only one of which is the library above.

I also tried this [GitHub library](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core).

It may be that none of them worked except the one above, but I'm reluctant to make that strong a claim.